# Glashow-Weinberg-Salam mass terms

Tags: mass, standard-model, symmetry-breaking, higgs, electroweak

At the end of spontaneous symmetry breaking I get these mass terms:

$$W_{\mu}^{\pm}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(W_{\mu}^{1} \mp i W_{\mu}^{2} \bigr )$$

$$\mathcal{L}_{mass}=\frac{1}{2} g^2 \frac{v^2}{4} W_{\mu}^{+}{W^{\mu}}^{-} + \frac{1}{2} g^2 \frac{v^2}{4} W_{\mu}^{-}{W^{\mu}}^{+}$$

So I have $$M_{W^+}=g \frac{v}{2} \quad  M_{W^-}=g \frac{v}{2}  $$

Is it right? Or there are too many terms and it is enough:

$$\mathcal{L}_{mass}= \frac{1}{2} g^2 \frac{v^2}{4} W_{\mu}^{-}{W^{\mu}}^{+} $$

Comment: "Or there are too many terms and it is enough:"
What did you mean?

Comment: Does $\mathcal{L}_{mass}= \frac{1}{2} g^2 \frac{v^2}{4} W_{\mu}^{-}{W^{\mu}}^{+}$ give mass only to $M_{W^-}$ o $M_{W^+}$ or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notation $W^{-}, W^{+}$ may confuse in a sense that it may seem that here are two different particles which aren't connected by charge conjugation. But of course, $W^{+}$ is only $(W^{-})^{\dagger}$, so it is an antiparticle to $W^{-}$. So term $( W^{-} \cdot W^{+} )$ is simple $|W|^{2}$ (which is standard for the mass-term), and, of course, both of particle and antiparticle have the equal masses.

Also before making substitution 
$$
\tag 1 W^{\pm}_{\mu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(W_{\mu}^{1} \mp iW_{\mu}^{2})
$$ 
you can see that both of fields $W^{1}, W^{2}$ have equal masses. So of course that their linear combinations $(1)$ also have equal masses.

Comment: You've copied the error of missing $i$ in front of $W^2_\mu$, didn't you?

Comment: @LubošMotl : yes, you're right.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I have a last question. A term like $\mathcal{L}_{mass}= \frac{1}{2} g^2 \frac{v^2}{4} W_{\mu}^{-}{W^{\mu}}^{+} $ gives a mass of $ M_{W^+}=g \frac{v}{2}$ or a mass of $ M_{W^+}=g \frac{v}{2\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @Karozo : The mass traditionally fixes by the equation of free motion (which coincides with Klein-Gordon equation) $(\partial^{2} + m^{2})W = 0$. If you "neglect" the Higgs-interaction term you will give, by using Euler-Lagrange equation for $W$ or for $W^{\dagger}$. So for your notation the mass will be equal to $\frac{g v}{2\sqrt{2}}$ (note that I don't know the multiplying factor of the kinetic term in your notation).

Comment: Here I use the convention 
$$
L = -\frac{1}{4}G_{\mu \nu}^{a}G^{\mu \nu}_{a} - \frac{1}{4}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} - |D_{\mu} \varphi |^{2},
$$
$$
G_{\mu \nu}^{a} = \partial_{\mu}W_{\nu}^{a} - \partial_{\nu}W_{\mu}^{a} + \varepsilon^{abc}W_{\mu}^{b}W_{\nu}^{c}, \quad F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{\mu}B_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}B_{\mu} ,
$$
$$
D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} - \frac{ig}{2}(\tau \cdot A_{\mu}) - \frac{ig_{1}}{2}B_{\mu}.
$$

Comment: Ok, I use the same for the kinetic term. Thank you.